# Solving some integral equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, integral-equations

I couldn't solve the systems, I need plot graph of solution:

```
eqns = {
  y[t] == Intagrate[s^(0.5 - 1)*(-0.02*y[s] - 0.06*(Abs[y[s] + 1] - Abs[y[s] - 1]) + 0.01*(Abs[z[s] + 1] - Abs[z[s] - 1]) - 0.02*(Abs[y[s - 0.1] + 1] - Abs[y[s - 0.1] - 1]) + 0.01*(Abs[z[s - 0.1] + 1] - Abs[z[s - 0.1] - 1]) - 0.4) ds, {s, 0, t}], 
  z[t] == Intagrate[s^(0.5 - 1)*(-0.03*y[s] - 0.03*(Abs[y[s] + 1] - Abs[y[s] - 1]) - 0.02*(Abs[z[s] + 1] - Abs[z[s] - 1]) + 0.01*(Abs[y[s - 0.1] + 1] - Abs[y[s - 0.1] - 1]) + 0.01*(Abs[z[s - 0.1] + 1] - Abs[z[s - 0.1] - 1]) + 0.1) ds, {s, 0, t}]
};
sol = DSolveValue[eqns, {y[t], z[t]}, t]
Plot[Flatten[sol], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Ummm... Integrate, not Intagrate.

Comment: Did not use code completion? in V 12.1, when typing `Int` it will put up a pop-up menu with choice of commands, then select the command that way from the menu. This saves time and most important, save making such typos which I would make otherwise myself also all the time since Mathematica commands are loooong. I recommend using the command completion.

Comment: Do I solve equation  true? DSolve is true?

Comment: @aysen:  Hey:  You will never solve your problem, and are not likely to get additional help if you leave ABSOLUTE errors in your code, after these errors have been pointed out.  First, it shows disrespect for those who have tried to help you.  Second, it shows you are likely unteachable.

Comment: Its my first message and im trying to learn but i couldnt understand why you insult me

Comment: @David Please remember to be nice.  You have a good point but you need not jump to the conclusion that aysen is "likely unteachable" to make it.  aysen, are you aware that you can edit your Question?  If obvious syntax errors remain it is likely to be closed as "A simple mistake or easily found in the documentation."

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, aysen! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 6):

First, you don't need `ds` in your `Integrate` arguments:

```
eqns = {
  y[t] == Integrate[s^(0.5 - 1)*(-0.02*y[s] - 0.06*(Abs[y[s] + 1] - Abs[y[s] - 1]) + 0.01*(Abs[z[s] + 1] - Abs[z[s] - 1]) - 0.02*(Abs[y[s - 0.1] + 1] - Abs[y[s - 0.1] - 1]) + 0.01*(Abs[z[s - 0.1] + 1] - Abs[z[s - 0.1] - 1]) - 0.4), {s, 0, t}], 
  z[t] == Integrate[s^(0.5 - 1)*(-0.03*y[s] - 0.03*(Abs[y[s] + 1] - Abs[y[s] - 1]) - 0.02*(Abs[z[s] + 1] - Abs[z[s] - 1]) + 0.01*(Abs[y[s - 0.1] + 1] - Abs[y[s - 0.1] - 1]) + 0.01*(Abs[z[s - 0.1] + 1] - Abs[z[s - 0.1] - 1]) + 0.1), {s, 0, t}]
};
```

To solve a system of differential equations, you don't need [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html).  I think your `eqns` are equivalent to the delay differential equations

```
deqns = D[eqns, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unfortunately these can't be solved analytically by [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html), so you will need to solve them numerically with [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html).  You'll need to give initial conditions, particularly to plot the results.  You'll also need a time domain, which I guess from your code is from $t=0$ to $t=1$.  You can't start right at $t=0$ because of the singularity of dividing by $t$, so I just picked the initial time `tmin=10^-5` and made up initial conditions.

```
{tmin, tmax} = {10^-5, 1};
sol = NDSolve[{deqns, y[tmin] == 0.1, z[tmin] == 0.1}, {y, z}, {t, tmin, tmax}][[1]];
Plot[Evaluate[{y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, tmin, tmax}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please clarify your question if this isn't what you want.

Comment: thank you but it isnt same, i need integral equation

Comment: @aysen I might be wrong, but if you differentiate your integral equations, you get the ones I solved (fundamental theorem of calculus).  I'll add this to my answer.  Anyhow, I don't think `DSolve` or `NDSolve` can solve integral equations directly.

Comment: @aysen, please go [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, so that you can regain access to this question.